# Connect to multiple oracle databases in a singe file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns something like below.

```
col1 col2
ABC  DB1
XYZ  DB2
PQR  DB1
LMN  DB3
```

I need to read this excel file and based on the value of col2 I need to fetch some records related to col1 in that database. For each database username host password is different.

I am using cx_oracle library for connecting to my databases.What is the best way to handle this kind of requests in python. I worked with connecting to single db but here I need to connect to multiple databases.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't know Python, but - what do you call a "database" here? Is it really a different **database**, or is it a different **schema** (user) in the same database?

Comment: Regardless of whether you mean different DB (in Oracle terms) or different users, the general technique is to call `connect()` for each, passing the appropriate credentials and connection string.  Depending on security requirements it's possible for one DB user to see another user's tables.  If you update your question with more detail about what you doing with the data, a more detailed answer could be given.  Also mention how many users are involved so we can advise on best connection management techniques.

Comment: I have around 14000 rows like this and 7 databases in total. Once I query the data I need to move that data to one excel sheet. Its different database in total not different user.